# How to reconcile two dogs?

Tags: dogs

**Background:**

I'm visiting my parents for a while, they have a mixed-breed dog who is friendly and i brought mine, a mixed-breed dog too, who is kinda aggressive sometimes with others dogs.

Both dogs were friends to each other, but today they had a fight over their plate of food, now if both see each other, they will fight.

**Question:**

What i can do to avoid more fights?,  both dogs used to play and be friends.
I can't go back to my  home with my dog, and need to stay a few more days (or until the quarantine is lifted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step should be **going on a walk with both dogs** and at least 2 people, each holding one dog. Start walking with both humans in the middle and the dogs on either side. Just walk like that for at least 5 minutes and keep the dogs seperated. Once they are calm and in the mood for walking, you can allow the dogs to walk side by side or play with each other.

What this does is showing both dogs that the other one can and will behave in a social manner. It also puts them together in a pack, since you all (dogs and humans) form a social group that works (or rather *walks*) together. This is the first step of reconciliation.

Next is to **seperate their food bowls**. Food is the number one reason for aggression in multi-pet homes, especially if both pets don't know each other very well. Either feed them at seperate times or in seperate rooms.

And last but not least, **know the hierarchy**. Both of them have a clear understanding of who is higher ranking than the other and they communicate this to each other via body language. If you happen to give both of them a treat, but you offer it to the lower ranking dog first, the higher ranking one might become aggressive. In the natural social structure of dogs the highest ranking one always eats first, so by eating the treat the lower ranking dog challanges the dominance of the other one, who then starts a fight.
If you're not sure which of your dogs is higher ranking, offer both treats to both dogs at the same time (one in each hand).

Bonus: Do some obedience training with both dogs at the same time. That can be as simple as "sit", "lay down" and "come here", or more complex commands, depending on what they know. This puts them together as a pack and can be a pleasant situation (if they get treats for following the commands). Don't forget to give the treat to the higher ranking dog first.

Comment: How much time should i wait for them too 'cool down' and take them on a walk?

Comment: @B.J.A.A. Watch their body language. If their tails are wagging quickly and they ignore anything but the other dog, they're too excited. If their tails are wagging slowly and they sniff around, they have calmed down and accepted the presense of the other dog.

Comment: Looks they have forgotten the fight, they don't play but don't fight either when together, thank you

Comment: All the above will take some time. If just for "a few days more", consider separating them until you leave.